# What is faster way to merge two DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas

I am sorry that this may be already asked or solved. Since I even don't know right phrase, I am asking here. I need to produce third dataframe from two datafrae as shown example below:

df1:

```
group   subject     value
A       Math        10
A       Science     30
B       Science     40
```

df2:

```
Group
A
B
C
D
E
```

Result needed (df3):

```
group   subject     Value
A       Math        10  
B       Math        10
C       Math        10
D       Math        10
E       Math        10
A       Science     30  
B       Science     40
C       Science     30
D       Science     30
E       Science     30
```

Is there better, faster way produce df3?

The way I did is:

1. Sort `df1` by `[subject, value]`.
2. Get unique (df_unique) subject from df1. I use Group by `subject` and head(1)
3. Loop (df_unique) and and produce df as below:

--

```
A       Math        10
B       Math        10
C       Math        10
D       Math        10
E       Math        10
```

Concat, and loop unless df_unique is finish.

But this very slow when we large number of rows. I am looking faster, better solution.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: How are you deciding if the values for "Science" should be 30 or 40?

Comment: @not_speshal, pick smallest one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set your index on `df1` to be a multi-index on `'group', 'subject'`, then reindex to what you want, and finally fill the `NaN`s:

```
>>> idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([
...     df2['Group'].values,
...     df1['subject'].unique()
... ], names=['group', 'subject'])
>>> df1 = df1.set_index(['group', 'subject']).reindex(idx)
>>> df1.fillna(df1.groupby('subject').transform('min')).astype(int).reset_index()
  group  subject  value
0     A     Math     10
1     A  Science     30
2     B     Math     10
3     B  Science     40
4     C     Math     10
5     C  Science     30
6     D     Math     10
7     D  Science     30
8     E     Math     10
9     E  Science     30
```

Comment: df1 = df1.set_index(['group', 'subject']).reindex(idx) has error ValueError: cannot handle a non-unique multi-index!

Comment: @KrishnaSunuwar then your example is incomplete, you have duplicate (group, subject) pairs in your `df1`. You’ll need `.drop_duplicates()` before `.set_index()`, or if you want to keep them then it’s not clear what you want to happend with those elements. Also you still haven’t said how missing values should be filled, answers are just guessing by taking the first value per subject.

Comment: I can not drop duplicate, they are needed. It will pick lowest value for missing i.e. for Math, it will pick 10 as it is only option. For science it will 30, as 30 is smaller than 40.

Comment: thank you, doing df1['subject'].unique() removes value that I need. as I commented, fill with lowest value i.e. 30

Answer (score 1):

Try with `pivot` + `reindex` then `melt` with `transform` fill the na

```
out = df1.pivot(*df1).reindex(df2.Group).reset_index().melt(['Group'])
out['value'].fillna(out.groupby('subject')['value'].transform('first'),inplace=True)
out
Out[483]: 
  Group  subject  value
0     A     Math   10.0
1     B     Math   10.0
2     C     Math   10.0
3     D     Math   10.0
4     E     Math   10.0
5     A  Science   30.0
6     B  Science   40.0
7     C  Science   30.0
8     D  Science   30.0
9     E  Science   30.0
```

Comment: out = df1.pivot(*df1).reindex(df2.Group).reset_index().melt(['Group'])
 has error like -> ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape